# How do you use MediaControllerCompat to control the current player?

Tags: android, mediacontroller, android-music-player, android-mediasession

My app is not the media player. I just want to be able to control the current media player using the new [MediaControllerCompat](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/media/session/MediaControllerCompat.html) class. Currently I am using [MediaSessionManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/session/MediaSessionManager.html) but want to upgrade to the new compat classes.

How do I instantiate the MediaControllerCompat class when I don't have a token or MediaSessionCompat to instantiate it with? I am hoping to get some example code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I asked Ian Lake, the Google dev who did the video on MediaSessionCompat, who said it is not possible (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FBC1FgWe5X4). We still have to use MediaSessionManager.

Comment: Is it also possible to get the currently played song information (and when it stops playing) of other apps ?

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can do it like this:

```
MediaSessionManager mm = (MediaSessionManager) context.getSystemService(Context.MEDIA_SESSION_SERVICE);
List<android.media.session.MediaController> controllers = mm.getActiveSessions(null);
for (android.media.session.MediaController controller : controllers) {
    MediaControllerCompat compat = new MediaControllerCompat(context, MediaSessionCompat.Token.fromToken(controller.getSessionToken()));
        
        // or if you wana use more powerful media2 MediaController
        MediaController controller2 = new MediaController.Builder(context)
                .setSessionCompatToken(MediaSessionCompat.Token.fromToken(controller.getSessionToken()))
                .setControllerCallback()
                .build();
```